# Split string with | character in Bash and export environment variables from first row

Tags: bash, sed, environment-variables

I have the following string which I get from a web service:

```
user@server:~# cat test.txt
account|uname|upass|mac|ip|tariff|download|upload
11122|24a43cda22b2|O3v2L2oPE9|24:A4:3C:DA:22:B2|192.168.1.2|7|12582500|2097000
```

First row are column names, and the second are their respective values. Note that the response always returns these two rows, not more. I cannot use JSON or other structured response format and this is what I have to work with.

My goal is to split all of these values by their separator character `|` and set environment variables (or variables in the context of my `.sh` script) by using column names as variable names.

So far, I am able to split both lines with `|` separatelly, using the following command:

```
user@server:~# head -n1 test.txt | sed 's/|/\n/g'
account
uname
upass
mac
ip
tariff
download
upload

user@server:~# head -n2 test.txt | sed 's/|/\n/g'
11122
24a43cda22b2
O3v2L2oPE9
24:A4:3C:DA:22:B2
192.168.1.2
7
12582500
2097000
```

From here I'd like to define variables, ie. `$account, $uname`, etc. to have values of:

```
$account = 11122
$uname = 24a43cda22b2
```

To have them as system environment variables (until reboot or next execution of my `.sh` script) or in the context of the shell script itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Take 3: `awk` as requested

```
$: awk -F'|'  'BEGIN{ ORS="" }
  NR == 1  { for ( i=0; i <= NF; i++ ) { arr[i] = $i;                  }; }
  NR == 2  { for ( i=1; i <= NF; i++ ) { printf "%s=%s\n", arr[i], $i; }; }
' test.txt > /tmp/vars
$: . /tmp/vars
```

> Take 2: Rewrite for `sh`

Hope this helps. :)

```
$: cat parse
#! /bin/env sh

sed -n '
  s/[|]/\n/g
  1 w /tmp/names
  2 w /tmp/vals
' $1

paste /tmp/names /tmp/vals | sed 's/\t/=/' >/tmp/vars

$: cat /tmp/vars
account=11122
uname=24a43cda22b2
upass=O3v2L2oPE9
mac=24:A4:3C:DA:22:B2
ip=192.168.1.2
tariff=7
download=12582500
upload=2097000

$: . /tmp/vars
$: echo $account
11122
```

> Original for reference

`printf -v` will write to a specified variable name for you.

```
$: cat parse
#! /bin/env bash

{ IFS='|' read -a headers
  IFS='|' read -a data
} < $1

declare -i ndx=0
for h in "${headers[@]}"
do  printf -v "$h" "%s" "${data[ndx++]}"
done

echo "account=$account uname=$uname upass=$upass mac=$mac ip=$ip tariff=$tariff download=$download upload=$upload"
```

Executed as:

```
$: parse test.txt >vars
```

Output:

```
$: cat vars
account=11122 uname=24a43cda22b2 upass=O3v2L2oPE9 mac=24:A4:3C:DA:22:B2 ip=192.168.1.2 tariff=7 download=12582500 upload=2097000
```

to load those values into scope:

```
$: parse test.txt >vars
$: . vars
```

Even in `sh`, sourcing the output should do what you need.

Comment: You can actually use `printf -v "${headers[i-1]}" "%s" "${data[i-1]}"` and dump the `n=$((i-1))` since indexing is an integer context, but I wanted it to be clear to read.

Comment: This is much more appropriate than the accepted answer.  I would recommend avoiding `seq` and just iterating over the array.  Something like `i=0; for k in "${headers[@]}"; do echo printf -v "$k" "${data[$((++i))]}"; done`

Comment: @PaulHodges I like this answer better as well, although I need to test it on my specific minimalist Linux environment. I can also `source` this script to get the variables exported in the scope of the [current] shell session?

Comment: @omerowitz Yep, you can source it the same way. I agree this is the better solution!

Comment: @PaulHodges Small help: how do I place this in a `.sh` file and inject a file into it? ie. `./script.sh test.txt`?

Comment: @PaulHodges Other thing I forgot to mention is that I am also limited to use `sh` instead of `bash` interpreter.

Comment: That makes a big difference. :)  Do you have `bash` available? I added a bit, so you should be able to just run it, redirect output to a file, and then source that file.

Comment: @PaulHodges Sadly, I do not. On the testing Ubuntu I do, but on the production servers (which counts in thousands), I sadly do not.

Comment: Ah. Ok then, Will see if I can generate a functional alternative. Gimme a bit.

Comment: @PaulHodges Absolutelly wonderful now! Thank you ^^ Answer accepted and thanks for keeping both references!

Comment: Happy to help. ;)

Comment: @PaulHodges Unfortunatelly, after I tested on my busybox (production servers), the `paste` command does not exist and I cannot install it on that machine. Is it possible to combine the two files with `awk` that way as you're doing with `paste`?

Comment: Lots of ways. Sec.

Comment: Easier if we're using `awk` to just use `awk` to write the output file to source, lol

Comment: Now it works flawlessly! You sir are a magician in a shell. Thank you a bunch!

Comment: I'm just persistent. >;o]

Answer (score 1):

This does what you want :

```
awk -F'|'  'BEGIN{ ORS="" } { for ( i=1; i<= NF && NR == 1; i++){ arr[i]=$i  } ; if (NR == 1)  next ; for ( i=1; i<= NF ; i++ ) { print arr[i]"="'\''$i'\''"\n" } } ' input.txt


account=11122
uname=24a43cda22b2
upass=O3v2L2oPE9
mac=24:A4:3C:DA:22:B2
ip=192.168.1.2
tariff=7
download=12582500
upload=2097000
```

EDIT : The dollar symbol is not needed when declaring.
EDIT : In order actually set this as environment variables you can redirect the output of it to the file **/etc/environment** as in here :

```
awk -F'|'  'BEGIN{ ORS="" } { for ( i=1; i<= NF && NR == 1; i++){ arr[i]=$i  } ; if (NR == 1)  next ; for ( i=1; i<= NF ; i++ ) { print arr[i]"="'\''$i'\''"\n" } } ' input.txt >> /etc/environment
```

You need sudo of course

Hope it helps!

Comment: No. It does not export variables. Read my question again.

Comment: I have edited my answer. In order to set these values as environment variables you need to define them somewhere. /etc/environment is a good place. To accomplish this simply redirect the output. Remember that you need to have sudo access to modify that file I mentioned, also, you will need to log out and in to see the changes reflected.

Answer (score 1):

If the headers are fixed a `read` is enough:

```
IFS='|' read account uname upass mac ip tariff download upload < <(tail -n1 test.txt)
echo $account $ip
```

Output:

```
11122 192.168.1.2
```

Answer (score 1):

Using paste and GNU sed:

```
. <(paste -d= <(sed -n '1s/|/\n/gp' test.txt) <(sed -n '2s/|/\n/gp' test.txt))
```

Or if GNU datamash is available:

```
. <(datamash -t '|' --output-delimiter='=' transpose < test.txt)
```

Then:

```
echo $account $mac $ip
```

Will output:

```
11122 24:A4:3C:DA:22:B2 192.168.1.2
```

Comment: `paste` is not available. I am running this under `sh` and `bash` is not available either. I have the following to work with: `read`, `awk`, `sed`, `head`, `cat`, `grep`, and other basic programs. I am running this on busybox/mips GNU linux.